# Repositories URL in Jenkins + Git

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Jenkins + Git as our build environment. Jenkins deploys on server1 and Git deploys on server2. but I don't know how to fill repository URL. I filled this field something like \server2\Solution, but git always return error code 128 and says it doesn't appear to be a git repository.

Note: I use local repository since our IT don't allow us use SSL server. I must use "local address/repository"

Comment: What command do you use to clone your repository? You should find the correct "repository URL" there.

Comment: I tried "git clone //server2/directory/solution C:/localAddress" and success. However, when I just copy-paste "//server2/directory/solution" to "repository URL", jenkins reported it's not a git repository. BTW, I use Jenkins Git plugin and really wonder if it is a problem of this plugin.

Comment: You did the clone from the same server as the jenkins? try file:////server2/directory/solution. (but I'm not sure how many slashes are correct for those windows location things.) - Otherwise look at [git-daemon](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) and use a git:-URL.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you have to copy your source code to `<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/<Project Name>/workspace` and execute it.