# Jenkins on OS X Local Git Repository URL

Tags: git, macos, jenkins

I have seen similar questions to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861048/repositories-url-in-jenkins-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498554/jenkins-linking-to-my-local-git-repository) but the URL structure doesn't seem to work for me and I'm getting a slightly different error.  I feel like I am missing something easy here so what Repository URL would I use for a local OSX path, that does contain an active git repo, with a remote on Github.   **Note I do not want to use the Github remote as I'm testing build triggers when commits are done locally**

**Repository URL**
`file:///Users/<myname>/Documents/<myproject>`

**Error**

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h file:///Users/<myname>/Documents/<myproject> HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '/Users/<myname>/Documents/<myproject>' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**12/10/15 Update**
To elaborate on this a bit more, I see the GIT plugin instructions in Jenkins referencing valid URL's, ending in `.git`.  In the directory in question, I do have the `.git` directory and have also attempted that structure (e.g. `file:///Users/username/Documents/blog.git`), but that also fails.  I feel like I'm missing something but can't quite place it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know it's 8 years later, but did you fix this?